# Can the Zurb plugin “twentytwenty” be run in a Foundation 4 Reveal Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to run a Zurb TwentyTwenty (before and after slider view) plugin *inside* a Foundation Reveal Modal?  I can get the modal to fire and the Header is shown, but not the plugin.  The plugin *does* work on the page in a standard column and I even tried commenting it out to see if that was it.  Here is the code I set for the modal:

```html
<!-- Modal Box -->
<div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal">
    <h3><font color="red">See the difference we can make</h3></font></hr>
    <div class="twentytwenty-container">
      <img src="img/rjh_before.jpg" />
      <img src="img/rjh_after.jpg" />
    </div>
    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
<!-- Modal Box end -->
```

And here is the trigger link:

```html
<a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal2">Modal Version of the 20/20 slider</a>
```

This is the first project I have done with Foundation and though I am learning fast, this one has me stumped.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer myself; it's a bug in Reveal.  Found on GitHub here:

[Squashed picture when using Orbit in a Reveal - Issue #2809](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/2809#issuecomment-22496896)

Added this code before the script for reveal:

```
var resize_window = function(e) {
$(window).trigger('resize');
}

$(document).foundation('reveal', {'opened' : resize_window});
<!-- Not used in my case, but additionally for running Orbit -->
$(document).foundation('orbit')
```

Works a treat!

Comment: I had the same problem when using other sliders and also when using google maps. When I use $(document).foundation('reveal', {'opened' : resize_window}); do you think it should work with other sliders as well ? Thanks a lot!